# How to store salted cod?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, fish, cod

Salted cod is a famous dish in Portugal and I would like to prepare it. It is common here to see the *whole* of a fish (well, without head, guts etc obviously) in supermarkets - like this:

[image]
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bacalhau.JPG)

I expect that it can be stored at home for quite a long time without refrigeration. However I'm not sure. What is the best way to store salted cod? For how long can it be stored? And, as a bonus question: what to do against the whole house smelling like codfish? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Still Tasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18260), 10-12 months, refrigerated.

To prevent odors, it should be left sealed in its original packaging, or put into an airtight container such as freezer bag (the freezer ones are better sealed and less permeable than the regular zip lock type bag).

Comment: And don't be afraid to double bag if you're not sure how well-sealed everything is. You really don't want fish smells slowly creeping into everything in your fridge.

Answer (score 4):

If you have space in your freezer, it's not uncommon in Portugal to see frozen "**bacalhau demolhado**" in portions. You can execute the soaking process, cut and store the fish in the freezer with skins and bones, well wrapped and it will keep good for a while. This will also give you the big advantage of having the fish ready to cook anytime you need it!

Comment: Note for readers: *demolhado* means it has been soaked and thus it is not (as much) salted.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a cod retailer. How long you can store it depends on where the fish comes from:

- **Norwegian** cod is salted and extra dried. When you soak it in water, it will expand into nice, thick steaks and it  does last longer, 8 to 10 months when refrigerated.
- **Nova Scotia, Canada** cod is semi-dry and, therefore, best when consumed within 3 to 4 months. When you soak it, its thickness will not change.