# Freezing prepared dry salted fish

Tags: freezing, fish

How does prepared dried-&-salted fish hold in the freezer?

The fish has been (properly) desalted, and, other than that, the recipe contains tomato (boiled down to a paste), tomato puree, onion, garlic and madame jeanette. There's tons of minor twists, but mostly it boils (haha) down to that.

I'm not worried if it's safe, I'm mostly wondering how it will keep texture wise.

The whole thing can (in general) be prepared in about two hours (including desalting), but I'm wondering if it's worth making it in bigger batches and freezing it. Desalting the fish produces quite a powerful smell, but refrying small batches of the prepared doesn't (as much). And while I don't mind the smell at all, my better half does ;)

**Edit:**

The salted fish is cod, and the fish has been desalted before cooking it with rest. The idea was to freeze the whole thing, but it's actually just as interesting to know if just the desalted cod will freeze nicely.

Comment: What kind of salted fish?  Cod, or something else?  Also, it's very unclear on whether you're talking about cooking the salt fish in the tomato sauce, and then freezing the whole thing, or just freezing the desalted fish.

Comment: @FuzzyChef: I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For freezing the desalted cod, see [one of the answers to this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33122/how-to-store-salted-cod).  Apparently frozen, desalted cod is a common supermarket ingredient in Portugal, which suggests that it's as good, or almost as good, as "fresh".  This is not a surprise, since salted cod has already been dehydrated once, so a trip through the freezer is unlikely to hurt it any.

For freezing the whole recipe: yes, I'd expect that it would freeze well.  The cod will freeze fine, and [tomato sauces also freeze well](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104690/canning-tomato-sauce-for-the-refrigerator/104696#104696), so I'd expect portions of the finished dish to be a good keeper.